# Why is DU causing high CPU usage?

Tags: command-line-interface, cpu-usage, du

On CentOS 6.5, `du -sk /home` and `sh -c (du -sk \/home) 2>/dev/null` run because a scheduled disk usage for /home, but `du` is causing 100% CPU usage. Plus, before it's even finished, another du gets run and it piles up, bringing the system down to its knees.

I've since disabled the automated checks, but I can't run `du -sk /home` manually either. `du` runs fine (fast) on other directories (though /home is the largest - 4912620 - it shouldn't take as long as it does)

I would like to find out why is DU causing high CPU usage on /home

---

UPDATE 1: A full restart (host+guest) solved the problem.

**UPDATE 2**: Problem came back. While du is running, CPU usage is split nearly half and half between (us) and (sy). (wa) never creeps over 1%. Also, IOWAIT shows [only disk writes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9IPp.png)?

Comment: It's likely to be iowait. Try running top or vmstat or iotop while doing du.

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU: surely IO wait would cause the du to relinquish the cpu ?

Comment: @lain I'm not sure about what you mean. 100% cpu can be caused by iowait (wa), userland (us) or kernel (sy).

Comment: Iowait can definitely cause the CPU load to creep up. If the disks are slow, particularly network disks, then this is more common.

Comment: Disk was an LVM volume for the guest KVM OS. OpCenter crew ran tests and found no physical problems with the disk subsystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered what the problem was when I came across [this post](http://blakemesdag.com/blog/2012/07/08/kvm-and-100-cpu-usage/).

`root> modprobe vhost_net
root> echo vhost_net > /etc/modules`

For some reason, the virtio interfaces were not loading the driver before. All is good now.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why exactly, but here's what I'd do to narrow down what is going on:

```
cd /home
for i in * ; do echo "Starting in ${i}..." ; du -s ${i} ; done
```

This will run "du -s" for each command inside the `/home` directory, and show you what it is about to do.  This is also assuming you are using sh or bash as your shell.

When you find which directory is causing the problem, move in one directory more, and see what happens there.  Also remember this will not check for hidden ("dot") directories at the level you start the for loop from.  You may need to check those as well, or modify the glob expression to include them.

Comment: There seem to be no abnormal delays or CPU spikes when I run the above command. If I run it for only /home with `--max-depth=1` I also don't get a delay/spike. It's only when I run `du -sk /home`.

Comment: Do you have any .dot directories in /home?

Comment: Directories named ".dot" ?

Comment: No, hidden files or directories inside /home

Comment: yes, .htaccess, etc

Comment: Is it possible one of those is the culprit?  Try:  ````du -sh .??*```` from ````home```` and see what happens.

Comment: du: cannot access `.??*': No such file or directory

Comment: You ran that from ````/home```` ?  If so, then you don't have any hidden directories inside /home itself...

Comment: yes. shall we continue in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12715/discussion-between-gaia-and-michael-graff)